# Haskell IO error handling during IO operation

Tags: haskell, error-handling, io

In the `System.Directory` library, `getPermissions` function could return IO errors.
The documentation says it could fail with `isPermissionError` or `isDoesNotExistError`.
How do I handle IO errors during calling `getPermissions`?

Attempt:

```
input <- try (do 
        permissions <- getPermissions filepath 
        print permissions)
case input of
        Left e  -> print "a"
        Right e -> print "b"
```

Error:

```
No instance for (Exception e0) arising from a use of ‘try’
The type variable ‘e0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Exception NestedAtomically
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Exception.Base’
  instance Exception NoMethodError
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Exception.Base’
  instance Exception NonTermination
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Exception.Base’
  ...plus 7 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  input <- try
             (do { permissions <- getPermissions filepath;
                   print permissions })
In the expression:
  do { input <- try
                  (do { permissions <- getPermissions filepath;
                        print permissions });
       case input of {
         Left e -> print "a"
         Right e -> print "b" } }
In an equation for ‘checkwritefilepermissions’:
    checkwritefilepermissions filepath
      = do { input <- try
                        (do { permissions <- getPermissions filepath;
                              print permissions });
             case input of {
               Left e -> print "a"
               Right e -> print "b" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it was impossible to figure out the type of exception (that is, the instance of `Exception`) you want to catch. One possible solution is providing a type annotation which specifies it, as in:

```
case (input :: Either IOError String) of
    Left e -> print "a"
    Right r -> print "b"
```

Alternatively, if you use `isDoesNotExistError` and friends in [`System.IO.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-IO-Error.html) to distinguish the error cases  the exception type will be inferred as `IOError` without requiring extra annotations.

A relevant discussion of basic exception catching practices can be found in [the `Control.Exception` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:3).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix (not a best fix) to this problem, replace

```
Left e
```

by

```
Left (e :: SomeException)
```

---

By the way, your code could be simplified like this

```
input <- try $ getPermissions filepath
case input of
    Left (e :: SomeException) -> print "a"
    Right e -> print "b"
```

And you really should improve those names in your code.